# How can I name my Database using EF Code First?

Tags: ef-code-first

I've got my EF Code First working exactly as expected aside from one small bit. I'm not sure how to name my Database File.

I'm using SQL CE, but I'm sure this applies to all forms of EF Code First.

Here's my DbContext

```
namespace MyApp.Domain.EntityFramework
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And when the database is created it's created as

```
MyApp.Domain.EntityFramework.DataContext.sdf
```

I'd prefer to just have it named

```
MyApp.sdf
```

Now I'm sure this is simple, but my Googling skills keep turning up examples where the database name is auto generated like mine.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a connection string (for example by creating a connection string named `DataContext` (your class name) in your config file, and set the desired name there.

Comment: so there's no way to override it programmatically?

Comment: You can use one of the overloaded constructors if you prefer to hardcode it. It's usually a better practice to have the connection string in the configuration file, though.

Comment: Thanks. I can probably research this from here on out. For future users searching this out, it might be a good idea to provide both examples (hardcode and connectionstring). see "[How do I write a good answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)"

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to do the same. Managed to end up with this:

```
public class ShopDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Information> OrderInformation { get; set; }

        public ShopDbContext() : base("Shop")
        {
        }
    }
```

It will name your database "Shop" so just replace what is in the `base("Shop")` with whatever you want to call your database. Hope this helps.